# ServiceStack returns empty XML

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, servicestack

I am new to the ServiceStack world but I think it could be a promising WCF alternative for the project I am working on. I've been testing the framework lately and everything JSON related seemed to work perfeclty. The problem is that I also have to use XML requests for some services and couldn't make it work.

I have implemented the hello world example and this request seems to work fine :

```
http://localhost:1337/hello/World?format=json
{"Result":"Hello, World"}
```

While this request is always empty :

```
http://localhost:1337/hello/World?format=xml
```

Do I have to configure the service or the listner in a particular manner for it to send valid XML back?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my own problem by implementing the same example as a Windows service instead of console app. I have no idea why it works now but it does ;).